# How to align elements in navbar right without using float?

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar with 3 sections:

- A logo
- A search bar
- A couple of menu options grouped together

I want it to look something like this where the logo is aligned left, the search bar has a left padding, and the grouped links are on the right:

[image]

If I try to float the group to the right, they don't vertically align to the middle.

```
<nav>
  <a class='logo-link' href="#">Example</a>

  <div class="search">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" method="get">
      <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>
      <input class="main_search" type="text" />
      <input class="inline_search" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="anchorLink">
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </div>

      <div class="anchorLink">
        <a href="#">Login</a>
      </div>

      <div class="anchorLink">
          <a href="#">Register</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've attached a [fiddle of an example](http://jsfiddle.net/DdM2M/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use

`text-align:justify;` + `display:inline-block;` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DdM2M/4/)**, you can then use : `vertical-align:middle;` to align your element to each other's middle **[DEMO bis](http://jsfiddle.net/DdM2M/7/)**

or

`display:flex;` + `justify-content:space:between;` **[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/DdM2M/5/)** You can then use `margin:auto;` to center on both axis **[DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/DdM2M/6/)**

Comment: Using both options adjusts the position of the search box, moving it slightly to the right. I get this is what the `nav > *` rule is doing, but the left border of the search box should not be moved.

Comment: wich method do you want to use ? once you choose and understand how it works, tune  your css . it can be the margin part, the text-align, the justify-content or whatever, either or both from nav or childs'div/ul , or even li) . You have many option to finish or tune childs element of nav.

Comment: @railsuser400 , i forgot to mention that you can tune width of div  or ul in nav, and have inside these , padding, margin and even make li, form or link float., the justified alignements methods i proposed you is a base to set first box on left and last on right. The rest of the styling is upon your choices. You could use display:table/table-cell too that works fine with IE8 ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) properties, Try `display:inline-block` instead `float` and Set `.search` class style like this:

CSS

```
.search {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    padding-top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10em; /* Reduce padding
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

**Added CSS class**

```
.nav--list{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/DdM2M/3/)

Comment: The links are not at the right of the nav element in your fiddle.

Comment: May be i'm using wide screen monitor you should adjust those `em`s according to your screen size :)

Answer (score 0):

**Efficient way to do this:**

**Html:**

```
<div id="header">
  <ul>
      <li><div>logo area</div></li>
      <li><div>search area</div></li>
      <li><div>other area</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header ul li{
  list-style:none;
  display: inline;
  padding-left:20%;
}
```

**Note:**
Different "display" option would give you different decoration of your elements. Here, display:inline would make the display vertical.

Check the W3schools lessons here for further understanding: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align your anchor-links to the right of your layout, you should

- Align the logo and the search left
- Align the option-links right
- By the way: I suggest to use an unordered list instead of several divs for your links

HTML

```
 <nav>
  <div class="logo">
      <a class="logo-link" href="#">Example</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" method="get">
      <input class="main_search" type="text" />
      <input class="inline_search" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <ul class="anchorLinks">
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    background-color:#EEE;
    height:25px;
    padding:10px;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    padding-right:20px;
}

.search {
    float:left;
}

ul.anchorLinks {
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul.anchorLinks li {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 5px;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9rLy/) here